# Create animation image going up with delay and duration when opening the activity jetpack compose

Tags: android, kotlin, android-jetpack, android-jetpack-compose

**I want your help.**

Everything is in the title, and i can't figure it out how i can do that... Help me please.
I used many thing like tween, enum class, and other, but didn't work, i want an initial value of 200dp and when the activity is open, after 2 seconde, the image goes from 200dp, to 100dp in 2 seconde.
Thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

with `1.0.0-beta04` you can use the [**`Animatable`**](https://developer.android.com/jetpack/compose/animation#animatable) API and the **`LaunchedEffect`** composable.

```
val animatedProgress = remember { Animatable(1f) }

LaunchedEffect(animatedProgress) {
    animatedProgress.animateTo(0.5f,
        animationSpec = tween(
            durationMillis = 2000,  
            delayMillis = 2000
        ))
}

Image(
    painterResource(id = R.drawable.xxx), "contentDescription",
    modifier = Modifier
            .size(100.dp)
            .graphicsLayer{
                scaleY = animatedProgress.value;
                scaleX = animatedProgress.value}
)
```

[image]

Thanks to [@Sheikh Zakir Ahmad](https://stackoverflow.com/a/67044486/2016562) for the tip about `.graphicsLayer`.

Comment: Thank you !!!! That's it, because in beta 3 and earlier, i'm so confuse with this type of animation

Answer (score 6):

The answer by @Gabrial is perfect but can be optimised by using graphics layer properties instead of size which will result in better performance as recomposition will not take place during animation.

**Edit. No offence**
@Gabrial.
Your anser will still trigger recomposition as your are not using the graphics layer with lambda modifier.

According to docs
If the layer parameters are backed by a androidx.compose.runtime.State or an animated value prefer an overload with a lambda block on GraphicsLayerScope as reading a state inside the block will only cause the layer properties update without triggering recomposition and relayout.

So the above code snippit shoud look like this

```
val animatedProgress = remember { Animatable(1f) }

LaunchedEffect(animatedProgress) {
    animatedProgress.animateTo(0.5f,
        animationSpec = tween(
            durationMillis = 2000,  
            delayMillis = 2000
        ))
}

Image(
    painterResource(id = R.drawable.xxx), "contentDescription",
    modifier = Modifier
            .size(100.dp)
            .graphicsLayer{
                scaleY = animatedProgress.value,
                scaleX = animatedProgress.value
}
```

Comment: Thank you ! I'll take that.

Comment: You are right. Thanks for the correction.